# Amazon Alerts (Monitor Amazon for new and upcoming products)

Tags: amazon, google-alerts

I have no Google account and can't use Google Alerts. I wish to monitor Amazon for new products.

For example get an email when there is an Amazon search hit for `Prometheus Certified Associate`.

Do you know how to setup such an alert? With a web search I found only price trackers, but not alerts for new and upcoming products.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize a website monitor for this, i.e. [distill.io](https://distill.io)'s extension, which you can run locally in a recurring manner of your choice. It works off prmise or in the background of your browser, given you use Chrome or Firefox. The browser would have to be running for this.
The local monitor would only really be important if you need to be in a logged in state, which does not work otherwise (without triggering all sorts of security wabobbashnagogga)

After installing you visit a ressource like for instance
"https://smile.amazon.de/s?k=Prometheus+Certified+Associate"
and let the monitor loose on the result page. For this you ask to monitor the resulting page. If there is no such product the result page (which you would monitor) says sth like "Use fewer keywords or try these instead".

You could set the monitor to this string via XPath (distill helps you with that a big deal). If there is no such string to be found, you get notified instantly in a manner preferred by you.
Amazon seems to be okay with that practice, as long as you keep the frequency of these checks in a reasonable range. Otherwise you run in a temporary ban by the server.